# OpenLayers JavaScript bug when dragging outside the map element

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to learn OpenLayers. But the project I try to create has a bug when moving the mouse outside of the map HTML element when dragging the map. When you try to navigate by keeping the left mouse button down and releasing it outside of the map HTML element.

Here is a basic project from the OpenLayers website that has this exact problem: [The Openlayers project](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vector-wfs-x7zwk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Here you can view the code of the project:

```
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from "ol/layer";
import { bbox as bboxStrategy } from "ol/loadingstrategy";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import { Stroke, Style } from "ol/style";

var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent) {
    return (
      "https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&" +
      "version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&" +
      "outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&" +
      "bbox=" +
      extent.join(",") +
      ",EPSG:3857"
    );
  },
  strategy: bboxStrategy
});

var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)",
      width: 2
    })
  })
});

var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: document.getElementById("map"),
  view: new View({
    center: [-8908887.277395891, 5381918.072437216],
    maxZoom: 19,
    zoom: 12
  })
});
```

Comment: I do not see any problem with your example.  What browser and device are you using?

Comment: @Mike There is actually something wrong here. If you take official example at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html and drag map with the mouse so that mouse ends far outside browser, WSF features being dragged into the view are not shown when you release the mouse. You have to click on the map to show them. I would call this a bug. In ol5 version of this example there is no such behavior.

Comment: It only seems to affect the official v6.2.1  6.1.1 is not affect nor is the master which is 6.2.2. dev version https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-wfs.html so whatever it is should be fixed in the next official release.  It seems the affect all the vector layer examples in the current release

Comment: @Mike Can you also have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352902/openlayers-fill-opacity-increases-after-repositioning?